# How to make item in ListView open a new empty activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm working on a simple notes app that contains a ListView and a plus button, I make the ListView item open a new activity when clicked

in this new activity also contains a ListView and a plus button

My problem is that every item opens the same new activity with the same data

So how to make each item in the ListView open a new **empty** activity with **new data**?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From first activity send some intent key say,"next" having value "new"  if you want second activity to be empty,
else send intent value "edit",if you want second activity to have some previous data.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                i.putStringExtra("next",new);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
```

and receive this data in another activity,
and if received data in another activity if new, then clear all editText.

like..

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String key=intent.getStringExtra("next");
if(key.equals("new"))
{
//clear all editText;

}else
{
  //load previous data;
}
```